# How to tell which PSP my pod is validated against

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When creating a simple pod on Kubernetes with an RBAC enabled cluster, and where a pod security policy is enabled for the role, how can I view which PSP is successfully used to validate the request? Cluster is deployed with kubeadm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the Pod Security Policy used by a Pod by looking at its annotations.

For instance:

```
kubectl get pod POD_NAME -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'
```